# Can't publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard

Tags: c#, clickonce

I' trying to publish ClickOnce Application to a webserver through sftp (Using Visual Studio 2015. The server is Centos 6.7).

My final config in the Publish Wizard:

```
The application will be published to:
sftp://10.1.0.88/home/www/sample/web/desktop/

Users will launch this application from:
http://sample.example.com/desktop/
```

When I published: (Output)

```
Connecting to 'sftp://10.1.0.88/home/www/sample/web/desktop/'...
Publishing files...
Publish success.
Warning: Unable to view published application at http://sample.example.com/desktop/publish.htm.
http://sample.example.com/desktop/publish.htm
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Nothing was added in `/home/www/sample/web/desktop/`. But it says **Publish success.**

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the deployment files were added to `/root/home/www/sample/web/desktop/`instead of `/home/www/sample/web/desktop/`

So I change publishing folder location from

```
sftp://10.1.0.88/home/www/sample/web/desktop/
```

to

```
sftp://10.1.0.88/../home/www/ecr/web/desktop/
```