# How to specify SFTP port for ClickOnce deployment C#

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, port, sftp, clickonce

I try to switch my ClickOnce Deployment from FTP to SFTP. The problem is, that a special port (e.g. 333) has to be specified.

While I am able to connect to the server via FileZilla, ClickOnce deployment does not work.

> Failed to connect to 'sftp://get.company.com:333/deployments/pzs2018/fast/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'sftp://get.company.com:333/deployments/pzs2018/fast'.  The server connection timed out.

Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5

It should work with standard ports according to:
[Can't publish a ClickOnce Application using the Publish Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709645/cant-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard)

Has anyone ever tried specifying ports? (unfortunately, I can't influence the server ports).

Comment: Are you sure that it's SFTP. Isn't it FTPS? What's your FileZilla settings like?

Comment: Also I think you should use [tag:visual-studio] tag rather than [tag:c#]

Comment: in the connected window tab of FileZilla, the tab title is "sftp://myusername@get.company.com:373"

Comment: So why do you use 333 in VS?

Comment: I use the same port in VS and Filezilla, I just changed the port in the initial posting to obfuscate the real port.